# Error when creating crystal report in WPF application

Tags: wpf, crystal-reports

I have a WPF application, PRISM + Unity, and have created a ReportingModule.

As of yet this is proof of concept.

My module simply has a single report that I want users to be able to select and view. I have the report.rpt file created and can preview the report, seeing data, however when I try and run my application I get an error 
"***The type or namespace name 'ReportingModule' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)***". If I comment out the code behind the .rpt file I can run my application. Why would simply creating a crystal report file break my application????

Confused.

Comment: So I take it you think your code is fine? Otherwise you would have posted some right?

Comment: Concur with Okuma.Scott.....and judging from your error you either need to add a using directive to your code or add a reference to your project.

Answer (score 0):

Add a using directive to your code or add a reference to your project to be able to use Crystal Reports. And if you add your sample code you may even receive more concrete help.